# AWS Cognito Auth with Phone Number OTP just like firebase, without Amplify

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am trying to enable login & Sign Up with Phone Number + OTP for a website (not Mobile) just like Firebase Auth offers.

I have looked up endless tutorials, almost all of which require AWS Amplify, which then requires knowing React/Angular/Vue (I'm not a front end developer). I followed tutorials like this one (https://techinscribed.com/passwordless-phone-number-authentication-using-aws-amplify-cognito/) and have created all the Lambda Functions, Cognito UserPools as stated in the tutorial. My roadblock is that it requires Amplify, and I just want to use vanilla JavaScript.

So I downloaded the AWS SDK builder with:

- AWS.CognitoIdentity
- AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider
- AWS.CognitoSync

I am using Zappa with Flask (serverless) to render HTML + JS to the user. I have everything else configured with API Gateway for the backend. All I need to do is authenticate users and generate sessions tokens for authenticated users, allowing access to their personal data, (like saved info, favorites, etc).

I am praying for someone to help me figure out how I can authenticate my users and generate the session/JWT tokens for my users. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: did you achieved with phone with otp in cognito

Comment: Yup. Implemented with Amplify Cognito Library. Look at the selected answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/) is just a wrapper around the core AWS services. The goal is to provide a boilerplate that takes care of the common access patterns. You don't have to use framework if you don't want to and can use the core services directly.

Before I point you to these low level APIs, it's worth noting that Amplify does have vanilla JS APIs as well. Refer the official docs [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/q/integration/js). You can handle authentication with only JS and not worry about any frameworks.

The docs for the Authentication module can be found [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js).

For reference, here are the scripts for Sign-up and login:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signUp() {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.signUp({
            username,
            password,
            attributes: {
                email,          // optional
                phone_number,   // optional - E.164 number convention
                // other custom attributes 
            }
        });
        console.log({ user });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing up:', error);
    }
}


async function SignIn() {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing in', error);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnSnow, if the answer did indeed address your question, do you mind accepting it. That way, others who stumble upon this can easily find the solution. Cheers.

Comment: My apologies @Mayank Raj, I'm new to Amplify so I am taking some time to read through the Amplify docs you have directed me to so that I can properly apply your suggested solution. I sincerely appreciate your response and will mark your answer as correct, and aim to further edit my original question with how I solved the problem with your suggestion once I have been able to apply it. Sorry for being a little slow, I am what you may call a 'noob' at this right now. Thanks for your patience Mayank

Answer (score 3):

[Cotter](https://www.cotter.app/) co-founder here.

We have a simple library that allows you to send OTP verification to users via SMS/WhatsApp with Vanilla Javascript.

**Guide:** [Sending OTP with HTML + Vanilla JS](https://docs.cotter.app/quickstart-guides/web-quickstart-with-js-sdk).

**Working Example:** [in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/client-side-working-example-hiy8w?file=/index.html) (you need to add your `API_KEY_ID`, which you can get [from the dashboard](https://dev.cotter.app/7d74bad6-d6aa-41e0-a1db-3fcfe45dc819)).

#### 1. Import the library

```html
<!-- 1️⃣ Get Cotter SDK -->
<script
  src="https://js.cotter.app/lib/cotter.js"
  type="text/javascript"
></script>
```

#### 2. Make a `div` with `id="cotter-form-container"` to contain the form

```html
<div
  id="cotter-form-container"
  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"
></div>
```

#### 3. Show the form

```html
<!-- 3️⃣ Initialize Cotter with some config -->
<script>
  var cotter = new Cotter("<YOUR_API_KEY_ID>"); //  Specify your API KEY ID here

  cotter
    .signInWithOTP()
    .showPhoneForm()  // to send OTP to using email use .showEmailForm()
    .then(payload => console.log(payload))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
</script>
```

#### 4. Get JWT Tokens

Check your console logs, you should get a response like this:

```
{
    "token": {...},
    "phone": "+12345678910",
    "oauth_token": {
        "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6I...", // use this
        "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlN...",
        "refresh_token": "27322:UYO4pcA17i4sCIYD...",
        "expires_in": 3600,
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "auth_method": "OTP"
    },
    "user": {
        "ID": "abcdefgh-abcd-abcd-abcd-f17786ed499e", // Cotter User ID
        ... // more user info
    }
}
```

Use the `oauth_token.access_token` for your sessions, [here's how you can validate the JWT token](https://docs.cotter.app/getting-access-token/verifying-jwt-tokens).

#### 5. Customize form

To show buttons to send the OTP via both SMS and WhatsApp, go to [Dashboard](https://dev.cotter.app/) > Branding.

Comment: Hi, nice product. The link titled guide in your answer (near the top) doesn't work, so maybe update it. I found this looking for alternatives to Firebase which is giving me a bit of a hard time (two of my real numbers are now unusable for auth on the Firebase platform after I switched projects/apps). Cotter looks nice regardless of whether or not I end up using it. Keep it up, there have to be better alternatives to services being half-assed by Google/Amazon.